# What will happen if there are 2 Appdelegate classes in the same file

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

In my xcode project there are 2 appdelegate classes. Will it work that way.I am having 2 view controllers and corresponding view controller classes.How will i connect an app delegate class to a view controller in storyboard.Is it possible to have more than one app delegates for a project?

Comment: how did u obtain two app delegates in a single project?

Comment: Why do you want more than one app delegate in your app?

Comment: UIApplicaitonDelegate follows singleton design pattern, so you will get the singleton UIApplication object.you dont need to take two different delegate classes, read apple's document https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I was having 2 functions that is to be done on 2 button clicks.So i copied and adjusted both projects into one.Currently i am having 2 appdelegate classes and the code is working fine.how can i optimize??

Comment: I don't why someone voted this question down !!! This is really a good question and also related to the programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should only use one application delegate.

What will happen if you have 2 delegate classes ? Answer is **nothing**.

It will only respond to the one reference which is there in the main class of the project.

main method will look like this,

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

for the universal application use,

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
// load viewcontroller 1
}
else
{
// load viewcontroller 2
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You really should only be using one `AppDelegate` for a Universal application. You can use this to share common things that you'll do in there. If you need to do something specific to a device type (i.e. - iPhone or iPad) then you can do a ternary expression like below:

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) ? NSLog(@"Load view for iPad") : NSLog(@"Load view for iPhone");
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you I don't know how you get two `AppDelegate` or why you need that but if you want to use both at the same time it's not possible. But you can call a particular `AppDelegate`, to do so you need to make condition on your `main.m` from where the `AppDelegate` are called. Though I have not tried it ever. But I'd like to make condition on `AppDelegate` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method rather than `main.m`. Best of luck.

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, (yourCoditionHere)?NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]):NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate1 class]));
```

Comment: This doesn't work, Always enters to the same delegate

Answer (score 1):

Just use the single one. And you can use the app-delegate class in view-controller using - `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`. This will return the an instance of your app-delegate class.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't set two classes as `AppDelegate` for an App.
Look at the `main function` where we are set class as `AppDelegate`...

```
int UIApplicationMain(int argc, char *argv[], NSString *principalClassName, NSString *delegateClassName);
```

In this function we can set only one `AppDelegate` by sending class name as argument 
(`NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])`  **-->** this is what `xcode` by default set for a `Xcode` project)

and `UIApplication` is a singleton class so we can set only one AppDelegate for an application

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO. Appdelegate is a singleton.